# Grails - what happens with save() if validate on save is false and domain object is invalid?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What happens if I call save() on a domain object but have set validate: false?

```
if (!domainObject.save(validate: false)) {
    def errors = ""
    domainObject.errors.each {
        errors += it
    }
    throw new Exception("Error saving domainObject: ${errors}")
}
```

I had though that I would get an exception here as save would return null, but I have a test expecting an exception but it's failing, as none is thrown.  If I turn on failOnError and don't turn off validate then the test performs as expected.  What does the save() return if the object is invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you turn off validation for `save`, then the save is executed without validating the instance beforehand. This may or may not work due to constraints from the underlying database. However in the case where the instance gets persisted, then `save` will return the (persisted) object and this will not enter your `if` branch.

If e.g. you have set `blank: false` or `min: 6` in your domain object, and the underlying DB does not know about such constraints, then the save can be made perfectly fine.

Comment: But surely then save() would return null if the save failed?  In which case, my if statement would be executed.

Comment: i can not speak for all DB backends there, but with SQL databases normaly an exception would be thrown with a message from the DB server.  above code is a pure gamble. `validate: false` is there for the cases, where you know, what you are doing (tests, batching, bootstrapping, ...)

Comment: It will in fact throw an exception if the database rejects it.